# Call overridden method with default arguments

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism, overriding

In my Kotlin project I have following situation:

```
abstract class BaseConverter<T> {
    abstract fun serializeValue(output: ByteArray, value: T, offset: Int = 0): Int
}

object BooleanConverter: BaseConverter<Boolean>() {
    override fun serializeValue(output: ByteArray, value: Boolean, offset: Int): Int {
        output[0 + offset] = if(value) 1.toByte() else 0.toByte()
        return 1
    }
}
```

Now from my test cases I try to call `BooleanConverter.serializeValue(array, value)` which does not give me an IDE error message. However when I try to run the test I get following error:

> Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong code generated [...] AnalyzerException: Argument 3: expected R, but found I

When I change my call to `BooleanConverter.serializeValue(array, value, 0)` everything works fine. But this makes my default value unnecessary. I also can not add the default value when overrideing the method because of:

> an overriding function is not allowed to specify default values for its parameters

So why can't I call the method only with two arguments and is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use default parameters only with variables of parent class type (in which method with default parameters is declared). Try as a workaround:

```
val c: BaseConverter<Boolean> = BooleanConverter
c.serializeValue(array, value)
```

or without creating an extra variable:

```
(BooleanConverter as BaseConverter<Boolean>).serializeValue(array, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) That is actually strange but I guess it works. Any ideas why this behavior comes from?

Comment: This post has some answers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700828/why-is-it-possible-to-omit-default-values-in-overridden-member-functions-of-sub

Comment: No, the answers there say why you don't need to repeat the default arguments in the subtype, but being unable to use them is a bug, I am pretty sure. Getting an `internal error` instead of a normal error message certainly is. @Cilenco You should report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ after checking for duplicates.

Comment: Also, without creating an extra variable you can write `(BooleanConverter as BaseConverter<Boolean>).serializeValue(array, value)`. Too bad Kotlin doesn't separate casts from type ascription as Scala does, so if `BooleanConverter` changes in the future it'll still compile but fail at runtime.